# Check if copy is in progress via command line

Tags: windows

I was wondering, is there any way to know via the command line in windows if a copy is in progress?

I'm writing a batch script to automatically shutdown all the computers on my network but we do transfer files between stations a lot and I need the batch script to check if such a copy is in progress.

Answer (score 0):

[AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com), that Jack of all trades, can help you here. A simple script like the following:

```
SetTitleMatchMode 2
if WinExist("Copying") or WinExist("Seconds remaining")
{ Exit 1 }
Exit 0
```

can be executed from a batch file:

```
AutoHotkey DetectCopy.ahk
echo %ErrorLevel%
```

*ErrorLevel* will obviously be **1** if there's a Copy dialog active, **0** otherwise.